# confusion with the concept of promises or event in JS ES6

Tags: javascript, events, promise

I'm struggling to come up with a clean solution for a design that enables a class to do something when something has happened in another class. I've been looking at Promises, callbacks and events but the application of Promises and events hasnt stuck yet.

My design issue is that I want a user to click on a button, which opens a filemanager (basically a popup with lots if images to select) and then update a thumbnail on the page when the user has selected an image from the filemanager.

I have a class that handles the controls on the main page which creates the filemanager class and opens it.

I want the main class to respond to the selected image and update the widget - I want the filemanager to just be responsible for selections not updating the main page.

So, how do I communicate between the classes so that the main class gets the selected image and does the update?

I've looked at loads of tutorials but confused on the implementation in this case.

Also - do events only relate to DOM elements. For example could I create a custom event to fire once a selection is made? confused.com

here#s the bones of my classes (removed some elements to keep brief):

```
export let fileImageWidgetControls = class {
    /**
     * sets up buttons
     * sets up control actions
     * opens filemanager
     * handles update image
     *
     * */

    options = {
        scope: ['file', 'image'],
        addBtns: {
            image: '#add-image',
            file: '#add-file'
        },
        editBtns: {
            image: [
                '.preview-image',
                '#replace-image',
                '#remove-image'
            ],
            file: [
                '.preview-file',
                '#replace-file',
                '#remove-file'
            ]
        }
    };

    constructor() {


        this.imageWidget = new updateWidget;
        this.imageControls = new ImageControls(this.options);
        this.initialiseControls();
        this.observer();


    }


    openFileManager = () => {

        const filemanager = new filemanagerHandler({
            images:true
        });

        filemanager.open();

/**HOW WILL THIS CLASS KNOW THAT AN IMAGE HAS BEEN SELECTED?**/
        let selectedItem = filemanager.getSelectedAsset();

    }


    /**
     * select image via filemanager
     */
    select = () => {


        this.openFileManager();

    };

    initialiseControls = () => {
        const module = this;
        this.options.scope.forEach((scope) => {
            //add
            $(this.options.addBtns[scope]).on('click', (e, scope)=> {
                e.preventDefault();
                module.select(scope);
            });


        });




    }
```

and here's the filemanager class (again trimmed down to relevant parts):

```
export let filemanagerHandler = class {

    constructor({

                    images = false, //show image panel
                    files = false, //hide files panel
                    upload = true, //show upload panel
                    serverURL = '/filemanager',
                    baseUrl = 'http://site.s3.amazonaws.com'

                } = {}) {

        this.options = {
            activeTabs: {
                images: images,
                files: files,
                upload: upload
            },
            serverURL: serverURL,
            baseURL: baseUrl
        }


    }

    /**
     * set up filemanager panels and controls
     */
    init = () => {
        this.imagePreviewModal = $('#imagePreview3');
        this.modalSelectBtn = $('#modalSelectBtn');
        this.tabClick();
        this.setUpPanels(this.options.activeTabs);
        this.setUpControls();
        this.uploadHander = new uploadHandler;
        this.observer();
        this.setUpEvents();


    }

    open = ()=> {

            colBox.init({
                href: this.options.serverURL
            });
            colBox.colorbox();


    }

    /**
     * set up controls within filemanager form (once loaded)
     */
    setUpControls = () => {
        let module = this;


        $('.select-image').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            module.handleSelection($(this), 'img');
        })

    }

    /**
     * close colorbox
     * selection then handled from within bind colbox closed
     * in calling class
     */
    closeColorbox() {
        colBox.closeColorbox();
    }

    setUrl = (url) => {
        this.options.serverURL = url;
    }




    /**
     * get the properties of the selected file
     * from the element and updates selectedAsset attribute
     * @param element (selected element)
     * @param type (image or file
     * @param callback
     */
    handleSelection = (element, type, callback) => {

        //set up selected element to be used by calling method in calling class 
        this.selectedAsset = {
            filename: element.attr('href'),
            id: element.data('id'),
            caption: element.data('caption'),
            type: type
        }
/** HOW CAN I GET THE CALLING CLASS TO RESPOND TO THIS EVENT/SELECTION?**/
/** IVE THOUGHT ABOUT A CALLBACK HERE BUT FEELS CLUMSY ?**/
        callback();
    }

    getSelectedAsset = () => {

            return (this.selectedAsset === undefined ? false : this.selectedAsset);

    }




    setUpEvents = () =>{
        //watch for colorbox to complete and initiate controls in the open document
        $(document).bind('cbox_complete', () => {
            this.init();
        });

    }
};
```

Comment: The filemanager may return a promise, as it makes only a single selection once and is then closed.

Comment: "*do events only relate to DOM elements*" - no